# Post com no fronend

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

Estou tentando fazer um Post de umas informações de um form mas não sei muito bem como fazer.

Este é meu form em C# :

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Enviar", "Mensagem", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "", @id = "formNovaMsg" }))
                {
                    <div class="">

                        <div style="display: none;">
                            <input id="LojaId" name="LojaId" value="@Model.LojaId" />
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: none;">
                            <input id="ClienteId" name="ClienteId" value="@Model.Mensagens[0].ClienteId" />
                        </div>


                        <!-- /.box-body -->
                        <div class="box-footer">

                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" id="Conteudo" name="Conteudo" placeholder="Escreva sua mensagem ..." class="form-control">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-warning btn-flat">Enviar</button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <!-- /.box-footer-->
                    </div>
                }
```

Para poder dar o post eu segui um exemplo que resultou na seguinte função:

```
    $("#formNovaMsg").ajaxForm({
    type: "post",
    beforeSubmit: function (arr, $form, options) {
        loading();
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if(!data.Erro){
            $("#conversa").append(data.Html);
            $("#formNovaMsg")[0].reset();
            $(".msgsis").fadeOut(300);
            var elem = document.getElementById('conversa');
            elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
        }
    }
});
```

Essa view é uma especie de chat a ideia e ele enviar a mensagem e já dar o post direto.

Quando estou tentando dessa forma estou tento o erro `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ajax is not a function` eu conferi os Jquery e não estão conflitando ( tenho apenas 1 , o 1.9.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro para você não dar um submit, se for um "chat em tempo real", faça via javascript mesmo.
Por exemplo: altere para não dar submit no seu html

```
<button type="button" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-warning btn-flat">Enviar</button>
```

e no seu javascript

```
 $('#btnConcluir').click(function () {
    Teste();
 }

function Teste(){
    var postForm = {
        'exemplo': $('#Conteudo').val() //pega o valor no campo digitado pelo usuário
    };
   // lembrando que 'exemplo' será o nome da variavel recebida como parametro, no C#

    $.ajax({
        url: "/WebService/Exemplo/Chat", //altere para o caminho que você vai querer mandar o post
        type: "post", //tipo post
        data: postForm, //os dados
        success: function (response) {
              alert(response["Mensagem"])
              //se deu certo
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //se deu erro
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Codigo C#

```
[HttpPost]
public void Chat(String exemplo)
{
    var resultado = new
    {
         Erro = false,
         Mensagem = exemplo;
    };

    return Json(resultado, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
}
```

Comment: ah intendi , mas no caso entao eu tiro aquele begin Form e deixo so um form de html mesmo ?

Comment: isso.. testa ai e avisa se funcionar ^^

Comment: vou testar agora , mas mesmo assim vlw ai cara.

Comment: Acho que deu certo , mas com o seu exemplo eu consegui intender muita coisa, eu estou seguindo um exemplo que usa ViewEnginer , mas ta retornando null, mas esse problema deu certo , qualquer coisa eu volto com outra pergunta, obrigado.