# Fazer um post em uma url externa

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, aplicação-web

Me colocaram em um projeto que foi feito em ASP .NET MVC 2 e precisam que seja feito a integração com o Itaú Shopline, baixei a dll do Itaú, fiz todos os procedimentos de criptografia, consigo gerar os dados, mas na hora de enviar para a URL externa o post retorna para o servidor do site e não para a url do itaú, o que faz todo sentido, então nessa parte que entra minha dúvida.

Como faço um post para uma url externa e envio as informações que preciso?

Segue o código que é dado de exemplo na documentação do Itaú:

```
    <FORM ACTION=”https://shopline.itau.com.br/shopline/shopline.aspx”method=”post”
name=”form1” target=”SHOPLINE”>
     <INPUT type=”hidden”name=”DC”value=”<%= dados %>”>
<br>
     <INPUT type=”submit”name=”Shopline”value=”Itaú Shopline”>
</form>
```

Abraços!

Comment: Você quer fazer o post a partir do seu controller? Tenta usar a classe [WebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9(v=vs.110).aspx),

Comment: Então, pelo que entendo, é como nos e-commerces que existem por ai, a partir de um botão na página é feita a chamada para uma url externa e dessa forma você faz a chamada do lado do client. Pelo que entendi da documentação do Itaú

Comment: De uma olhada [nesta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/150730/44744), tem uma demonstração de como fazer POST usando o ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, não sei se é isto que está procurando, mas pode ajudar.

DE:

```
<INPUT type=”submit”name=”Shopline”value=”Itaú Shopline”>
```

Para:

```
<input type="button" name="Shopline" id="Shopline" value"Itau Shopline">
```

Então no JS com Jquery

```
$("#Shopline").click(function(){
$.post(
     "Sua URL", 
      function(){
          //trata retorno
      })
})
```

Veja estes link: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/